# Is love in a human being immanent or is to say that heresy?

Tags: catholicism, love, heresy

In a paper I am writing I am trying to find a good word to describe that love (and compassion?) are inherent in every human being, and preferably that it comes from The Divine. According to Catholic doctrine can one state

> which in itself demonstrates the immanence of love and compassion in the human soul

is this an accurate description? Or is immanence an attribute that can only belong to God, or in this or some other way, is this heresy or too bold?

Comment: I don't understand what you're talk about. Also, Christians generally reject the idea that everyone is basically good.

Comment: @curiousdannii The question is not if love comes from God, it is, is immanence  a proper word to describe its presence in humans.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on [English.SE] instead.

Comment: @curiousdannii It is a theological question of the word's proper use with respect to Christianity. In other words can we say a human has a immanent attribute from God, or can we only say God has immanent attributes, in which case is it to bold to say that humans have such attributes. We know love comes from God, but is this the right word theologically?

Comment: I think you want to say, "..demonstrates the **innate** love and compassion...", or perhaps "inherent". Whether that's actually an accurate statement is a different question (though I think it is; I think the fall marred but didn't erase the image of God). As Jesus said, even those "who are evil, know how to give good gifts to [their] children").

Comment: @curiousdannii: Calvinists reject that. I don't know if it's fair to say that Christians as a broader group reject that. Many Christians would say that being made in the image of God means that all people are "basically good."

Comment: I think you're approaching the question from entirely the wrong angle. You should start by asking "What does the Catholic church teach about X?" not "I think X, does the church support me?"

Comment: @Flimzy I was just hinting at passages like Romans 3:10-18

Comment: @curiousdannii: I'm well aware of how the view is supported by scripture. I'm neither defending nor refuting it--I'm simply pointing out that many Christians don't interpret scripture that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

> **IMMANENCE** Presence or operation within someone or something. Total "within-ness." As an operation, an immanent act begins within and
>   remains within the person whom it perfects in the process. Thus acts
>   of reflection and love are immanent acts of a human being. They may,
>   of course, have effects outside the mind and will, but essentially
>   they arise within and stay within the faculties by which they are
>   produced. (Etym. Latin *immanere*, to remain in, hold to.)
>   *Source:* [Dictionary: IMMANENCE | Catholic Culture](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34094)

For a detailed treatment on immanence, please see [Immanence | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07682a.htm).

Can one say , *'that love (and compassion?) are inherent in every human being?'*

From the definition above, love ( = to will good to someone<sup>1</sup>), as an immanent act, is an operation [of the will], one must *want to do that immanent act*, therefore to say it is inherent in every human being would not be correct.

<sup>1. cf. [LOVE | Catholic Culture](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=34656).</sup>

Note: [Heresy](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33902) does not factor.

Perhaps for your paper you meant to state, *'everyone has the capacity of ...'*, which is a different topic altogether.